# Should we remove the "pythonic" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just rejected 2 suggested edit to the [pythonic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pythonic) tag. Not that the edits were that bad, but it just struck me that this tag seems useless. It's usually used on questions in conjunction with the "python" tag, so that seems highly redundant, and would encourage the spread of similar tags where any fancy terms describing the the virtue adheres to the principles of culture X.

I'd see mavenic pop-up for maven, or other abuses show up, when using the main tag relating to the technology would be sufficient.

**Do you think we should get rid of the "pythonic" tag (and other similar tags)?**

**Another alternative suggested by YannisRizos:** We could make "pythonic" a synonym of "python". I just suggested that synonym on the ["python" tag's synonyms page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/python/synonyms). You can vote there directly for adoption or rejection of the synonym.

Comment: The voting was completed, and [pythonic] is now a synonym of [python].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the question above, I find this tag (and others similarly describing adherence to the principles or philosophy of a tech group) to be highly redundant with the tag describing the tech itself.

Granted, there's an obvious difference in the semantics of the tags ("pythonic" for "python", "mavenic" for "maven", etc...), as one can write completely "alien" code for a programming language, or force a tool to be used for things it wasn't meant to do. So I can understand that they are meant to imply that the question focuses on a particular issue (using the tool the "right way", or at least the "intended way").

But still, I think this tag should die, as should any other tag that is a clear redundancy or very close relative of another tag.

I was really itching to go through all these questions and remove this tag in favor of just "python", but I wanted approval first.

Comment: _If_ we decide the tag is not useful, I think the easier solution would be to make [pythonic] a synonym of [python]. That way, if someone tries to use it in the future, it will be automatically converted to [python].

Comment: @YannisRizos: Entirely right, I had completely forgotten about that feature!

Comment: @YannisRizos: suggested "pythonic" as synonym for python. Feel free to vote or downvote there.

Comment: @YannisRizos: thanks for the edit as well... Couldn't remember the tag syntax and was just looking for the links. For the rest... I think I need sleep.

Comment: Heh, surprisingly I happen to have an answer score of 5 or more on the [python] tag and I can vote for synonyms (yay, rare opportunity to vote as a regular user!).

Comment: In regards to the fact that `pythonic` suggests a question that will focus on coding style in idiomatic python, we already have a `coding style` tag don't we? So `[python] [coding style]` ought to cover those bases. Agreed that it should be made into a synonym (though I either don't know how to vote for the tag synonyms, or can't).

Comment: Perhaps [pythonic] should be a synonym for [coding style] :P

Comment: @Standback: the voting was completed on Jun 17 to switch it set it as a syn for [python] (see Yannis's comment under the question). But if you think that's worth re-considering you could open a new thread I think.

Comment: No, no - I was only kidding on that. I'm in full agreement with the consensus, and my interest in the matter has devolved into aimless clowning around.